# Is it possible to get a list of DataTables from SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, datatable

I am trying to get a list of tables from my SQL Server database. I would like the `DataTable` object not just the `name`.

So far I have got:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Settings.Default.DatabaseString))
{
   List<DataTable> tables = new List<DataTable>();
   connection.Open();       
}
```

I can get the names of the tables using:

```
DataTable schema = connection.GetSchema("Tables");
foreach (DataRow row in schema.Rows)
{
    var name = row[2].ToString();
}
```

But I would like more information than just the name of the table I would like to return primary and foreign keys etc. Is this possible?

Comment: GetSchema returns also that infos provided you pass the correct set "INDEXES" etc...

Comment: `GetSchema` returns 1 data table and each `row` contains 4 columns which give the name of the table. Is there a way of getting a `DataTable` object for each table in my database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get infromations about the database, tables, columns and indexes with the [`Conenction.GetSchema`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.getschema(v=vs.110).aspx) overloads:

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(Settings.Default.DatabaseString))
{
    con.Open();
    DataTable tables = con.GetSchema("Tables");
    foreach (DataRow tableRow in tables.Rows)
    {
        String database = tableRow.Field<String>("TABLE_CATALOG");
        String schema = tableRow.Field<String>("TABLE_SCHEMA");
        String tableName = tableRow.Field<String>("TABLE_NAME");
        String tableType = tableRow.Field<String>("TABLE_TYPE");
        DataTable columns = con.GetSchema("Columns", new[] { database, null, tableName });
        foreach (DataRow col in columns.Rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",col.ItemArray));
        }
        DataTable indexes = con.GetSchema("Indexes", new[] { database, null, tableName });
        foreach (DataRow index in indexes.Rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", index.ItemArray));
        }
        DataTable indexColumns = con.GetSchema("IndexColumns", new[] { database, null, tableName });
        foreach (DataRow indexCol in indexColumns.Rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", indexCol.ItemArray));
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a list of possible values for `GetSchema`:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716722(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server is very open about [querying the catalog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345522.aspx). You can easily create the query that will return the data you require.

Multiple tables exists to help you:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.tables
SELECT * FROM sys.columns
SELECT * FROM sys.indexes
SELECT * FROM sys.objects o WHERE o.type IN ('PK', 'F')
```

Querying the name of the objects from any of these tables can be done with the system method `OBJECT_NAME`.